# Renaming the Sankey Chart Label using amchart4

Tags: amcharts, sankey-diagram

Is there any way to rename the label of different nodes in the Sankey Diagram using AmChart4.

Comment: Yes, there is. One way is through the [`name` adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/sankeynode/#name_adapter) of `SankeyNode`, accessed through `chart.nodes.template`, see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05rd3xo9/). For a complete answer, please share your code and details on how and when do you want to change the names.